# Option chain with nil bid quantity and price

Tags: options, call-options, put-options, option-strategies, option-exercise

Let's assume I bought a call option ABC CE @.50 and now its value is @.10.  There is no bid price or bid quantity.  Am I able to sell the option at @.10 anyway?

Answer (score 3):

$0.10 is the price of the last trade.

If the bid is zero then there are no buyers with active orders.

You can place an order to sell at 10 cents but it's not likely to execute unless a buyer shows up at that price.

Answer (score -1):

Place a Market order rather than a Limit order, if you want to exit out of your position.

Else, just prefer not to exercise your option/trade.

> ... As with all [options](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/americanoption.asp), the holder does not have an obligation to receive the share if they choose not to exercise their right...

Comment: You can't place a market order for zero.

Comment: Poor advice to enter a market order when there are currently 0 bids - a novice might be surprised to see a 0.005 bid pop up  and snap up the market order.